# Connecting and sending message between Spring WebSocket instances

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, stomp

I have multiple instances using Spring Boot WebSocket (created following the first half of [Spring's guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)). I need them to connect to other instances at specific hostnames and ports and to be able to send messages over the websocket connection using STOMP protocol.

### How can I connect to my other services over websocket?

### How can I send messages using the STOMP protocol (preferably using the same marshalling/unmarshalling magic I get with received messages)?

Things that don't answer my question:

- I have read [Spring: send message to websocket clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33977844/spring-send-message-to-websocket-clients) and [Sending message to specific user on Spring Websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367223/sending-message-to-specific-user-on-spring-websocket) but these and other questions seem to all assume that a client has already initiated a connection and that there are users and topics established. This is not my use case as my services are both server AND client.
- I am not using a cluster and I am not sharing sessions across instances as in [Spring Websocket in a tomcat cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26853745/spring-websocket-in-a-tomcat-cluster)

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you are looking for distributed websocket messaging server based on stomp protocol. Something like this might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26853745/spring-websocket-in-a-tomcat-cluster

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Websocket in a tomcat cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26853745/spring-websocket-in-a-tomcat-cluster)

Comment: @SepehrGH unfortunately that is not my use case. I am doing a practice implementation of some distributed system leader election algorithms. I do not need to share sessions across nodes/instances. There are no web browsers involved.

Answer (score 1):

I have found some resources that cast some light on how to accomplish this:

1. http://www.baeldung.com/websockets-api-java-spring-client
2. https://www.sitepoint.com/implementing-spring-websocket-server-and-client/#javaspringchatclient
3. http://useof.org/java-open-source/org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSessionHandler

number 3 is at least a complete implementation but is unfortunately devoid of comments to explain what's going on.